# How to build MFOC from sources on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, path, configure

I have to configure and make [GitHub | MFOC](https://github.com/vk496/mfoc), but when I run `./configure` it says:

```
# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
#Here the error
./configure: line 3930: syntax error near unexpected token `libnfc,'
./configure: line 3930: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))'
```

I have thought at 3 possible cause for the error:

1. The error occurrs becouse there are differences between the path or name requested.

In fact, synaptic says that libnfc in my Kali Linux is:

```
library: libnfc5, 1.7.1-b4
binaries: libnfc-bin, 1.7.1-b4
```

So maybe the problem is that 5 ahead libnfc

2. The path expected is different
3. Libnfc 1.7.1 is not supported, as last update (line 16 of [ChangeLog](https://github.com/vk496/mfoc/blob/master/ChangeLog)) is for 1.7.0.

Can you help me please?

---

I report the help for configure, maybe it is interesting

```
# ./configure -help
`configure' configures mfoc 0.10.7 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --runstatedir=DIR       modifiable per-process data [LOCALSTATEDIR/run]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/mfoc]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-silent-rules   less verbose build output (undo: "make V=1")
  --disable-silent-rules  verbose build output (undo: "make V=0")
  --enable-dependency-tracking
                          do not reject slow dependency extractors
  --disable-dependency-tracking
                          speeds up one-time build

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.
```

Comment: Does your `configure` script at line 3930 really contain `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))`? This is a macro that should be replaced by some shell script code. There might be something wrong with your `autotools` version.

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Kali question that has to do with programming and development

Comment: Please open `config.log`, find the part related to the `libnfc5` failure, and post the chunk with your question. It is probably missing the `libnfc5-dev` or `libnfc5-devel` package, so you don't have the header files you need. `$ apt-cache search libnfc` should tell you the package name you need to install. [Here](https://pastebin.com/6kDPz0uY) is what it looks like on Ubuntu. Notice the `libnfc-dev` package.

Comment: @Bodo [here](https://pastebin.com/9WKQYjiT) is my configure, I cannot deduce the error.

Comment: @jww In my [config.log](https://pastebin.com/8c911jHG) there's nothing about libnfc. I have also tried installing libnfc-dev and libnfc5-dbg (libnfc-bin, libnfc5 were already installed) but it didn' t worked.

Comment: @EnnioEvo Add the requested information to your question instead using comments to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not mean that there would be something wrong with `libnfc` on your system. **There is something wrong in the shell script `configure`.**

The `configure` script did not perform a check for `libnfc`. The error message is about a **syntax error in the shell script** at a line that was intended to do this check.

```
./configure: line 3930: syntax error near unexpected token `libnfc,'
./configure: line 3930: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))'
```

This doesn't exactly match the line numbers in the script you show on pastebin.
Here the error is at line 3963.

Script snippet starting at line 3949

```
...
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $am_cv_make_support_nested_variables" >&5
$as_echo "$am_cv_make_support_nested_variables" >&6; }
if test $am_cv_make_support_nested_variables = yes; then
   AM_V='$(V)'
 AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
else
 AM_V=$AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY
 AM_DEFAULT_V=$AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY
fi
AM_BACKSLASH='\'


# Checks for pkg-config modules.
LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION=1.7.0
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))

PKG_CONFIG_REQUIRES="libnfc"



{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for inline" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for inline... " >&6; }
if ${ac_cv_c_inline+:} false; then :
 $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
 ac_cv_c_inline=no
for ac_kw in inline __inline__ __inline; do
 cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
/* end confdefs.h.  */
...
```

Before the comment line `# Checks for pkg-config modules.` it looks like a normal configure script.

**The line `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))` is wrong.** This is autotools M5 macro code, not shell script.

From `{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for inline" >&5` it looks normal again.

The `configure` script is generated from `configure.in` or `configure.ac`. This source is a M5 macro script using special autotools macros. All text that is not a known macro is copied to the output unchanged.

The problematic line `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION, , AC_MSG_ERROR([libnfc >= $LIBNFC_REQUIRED_VERSION is mandatory.]))` is a M5 macro call `PKG_CHECK_MODULES()` with several parameters whereof the last one is another macro call `AC_MSG_ERROR()` with a quoted argument.

I don't know why this ended up in the configure script, but this is obviously wrong. Maybe there is a bug in the `configure.ac` script, maybe a wrong version of the autotools was used to generate the `configure` script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bodo, I was simply cloning the wrong branch. I know I'm a great noob, but slowly I'm learning. Thank you very much again.

Comment: If the solution was to use the correct branch you should add detailed information to your answer which branch you used when you got the error and which branch solves the problem. This would make the answer more valuable. Remove the "thank you" and info about being a noob. This is unnecessary. I also suggest to edit the title to something like this: Syntax error in configure script for MFOC at "PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libnfc, ..."

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading due missing pkg-config, to fix:
apt-get install -y pkg-config && ./configure